# How to handle multiple TcpClient clients simultaneously

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I usually write my socket apps with `UdpClient`, I like the way udp works. I just listen on a socket, anytime anyone has a request, I just get a little datagram, reply right back to that `client` via their `IpEndPoint`.

But with `TcpListener` it's seemingly much more complicated. I have to wait for someone to connect (via `server.AcceptTcpClient()`), then setup a while loop to receive data until there is no more data from the accepted `client`. Finally, `close()` the connection.

Is there a way to keep multiple connections open and receive bits of data without closing the connection at the end? It just seems so weird how much more complicated TCP is than UDP.

thoughts?

Comment: You don't need to close the connection at all, it can be left open as long as you like.  The problem is more likely that you **think** it needs to be closed.  Many issues arise with TCP simply because it isn't well understood how one **frames** your packets so that you know when a complete "message" has been received.

Comment: Consider using events or observables.